# Xamarin MVVM Display Data From Another Model/Table/Object

Tags: templates, xamarin, mvvm, carousel, observablecollection

New to Xamarin. What is the best way to display data I need from another table/model/object? Or don't at all?

I want to try System.Linq's Enumerable.Join but doesn't that defeat the purpose of an observable collection? I want to change things and insert records. I've been trying to use another model to group the information together but no luck.

Trying to use a carousel view with another group model wrapped around the info. Questions are coming from a working API. Thanks all.

Question

- qQuestion
- name

Answer

- pAnswer
- fQuestion
- Value
- Comments

ViewModel

```
                IEnumerable<QuestionModel> questions = await DataSource.GetQuestionsAsync(true);

            QuestionList.Clear();

            int k = 0;

            foreach (var i in q)
            {
                // questions for template
                QuestionList.Add(i);

                var c = k++;

                string s = (c + 1).ToString();

                var a = new AnswerModel
                {
                    pAnswer = s,
                    Posted = DateTime.Now,
                    fQuestion = i.pQuestion,
                    Value = i.Standard,
                    Comments = "Commnt here"
                };

                // template of answers for each question
                AnswerCollection.Add(a);
            }

            // templates
            foreach (var i in AnswerCollection)
            {
                var n = new GroupList<QuestionModel>
                {
                    pGroup = i.pQuestion.ToString(),
                    Name = i.Name
                };

                n.Add(i);

                GroupedAnswerCollection.Add(n);
            }

            //var g = AnswerCollection.Join(
            //    QuestionList,
            //    foreign => foreign.fQuestion,
            //    primary => primary.pQuestion,
            //    (primary, foreign) => new
            //    {
            //        Test = primary.pAnswer,
            //        Test2 = foreign.Name,

            //    }).ToList();
```

Xaml

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedCollection}"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               Margin="20"
                               WidthRequest="200"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding pGroup}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Other}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>


                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding pAnswer}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding fQuestion}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Comments}" ></Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>

                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

Comment: Where are you setting ```GroupedCollection```? The bindings inside a ```DataTemplate``` will have the binding context of the model that makes up ```GroupedCollection```. It looks like you're trying to bind to properties that are in Answer, but also in Question. That won't work. Is there a combined model you didn't put in the example?

Comment: I have the group list being created in the loop. Thats as far as I got. I also have a new ObservableCollection on the constructor. Is that what you mean? Also, if it won't work. What should I be doing instead? I'm learning and I need to learn proper way still.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the question what exactly it is you want to achieve. But in short. The purpose of a ViewModel is to process and format data in such a way that it is easily consumable from the View through simple bindings to properties.

Comment: gotcha. ok so my question is does the viewmodel only have a one to one relationship with data? or can it be one to many? I'm looking show each question (question model) with an answer (answer model) together in the same view so if it was a select statement in sql it would be the result of pQuestion, Name, pAnswer, Value, Comments from Answer Inner Join Question On Answer.fQuestion = Question.pQuestion

Comment: viewmodel has one to many relationship with data. it can come from any number of sources. view has a one to one relationship with the viewmodel(its binding context) with the exception of DataTemplates having a different binding context by default.

Comment: So using a carousel view, list view, etc. what is the best approach to show the name in question model if my item source has data from the answer model? That way the questions name can be seen while answering because pQuestion is just a primary key number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedCollection}"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <!--All properties inside this data template need to exist in the QuestionAnswer object -->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               Margin="20"
                               WidthRequest="200"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding pGroup}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Other}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>


                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding pAnswer}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding fQuestion}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Comments}" ></Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>

                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

ViewModel:

Backing property for the carousel view.

```
private IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> groupedCollection;
public IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> GroupedCollection
{
    get => groupedCollection;
    set
    {
        groupedCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedCollection));
    }
}

//Can pull information from multiple sources and package it for the view.
private void GetQuestionAnswers()
{
    //pulling data from 2 separate sources
    var questions = await QuestionApi.GetQuestions();
    var answers = await AnswersApi.GetAnswers();

    //use these to build QuestionAnswer list called questionAnswerList

    GroupedCollection = questionAnswerList;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ah gotcha. so create a model to combine the two. And that wouldn't affect the answer model for when I want to make changes later. Am I thinking right? I feel like I'm going to have a model for everything and their momma.

Comment: generally you'll have a model for the object you receive from the database. This can be used to store changes and then sent back, but you would have to design your endpoints to use the same model. in your case, you want to combine questions and answers to display so you need a common model. then when you send the changes back you just need to put them into any model to send back to your endpoint.